# How does for loop assignment work with the initializer variable in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, local, allocation

So from what I know in C, anything that is referenced must be stored in memory somewhere.
Variables stored in the heap can surpass its lifetime past its function call.
But here is a trivial example of an integer defined within a for loop, whose values are referenced at some point by an array outside of it.

If we printed out the array, we would get 0,1,2...7. 
Where are these individual integers being stored? If every array index was referencing
the same "int i", then they would all be the same number. But if each int was it's own
individual memory cell, this would imply all the ints are saved onto memory at some point?

```c
int main(){
    int arr[8];
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C has value semantics; the assignment operator means the value from the right hand side is copied into the memory location indicated by the left hand side.  This isn't establishing some kind of formula or equivalence

Answer (score 3):

The values are stored into the array `arr`.

In the line `int arr[8]` you are saying "Reserve enough memory to store eight integers". Then when you enter the loop, you are assigning the value from the loop counter `i` into each of those locations. After this assignment operation it doesn't matter what the value is `i` is, because the value is already in the `arr` array. In the example you posted, nothing is accessing the value `i` outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: Alright I think I get it then. 
int arr[8] reserves memory for 8 integers.
arr[0] = 0 says, copy the value of 0 into the reserved memory space pointed to by arr[0]

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and so on for all subsequent loop iterations.